# in php, how can get ID from android to send

Tags: php, android

I use eclipse to write android app and php website. Coding of the AndroidShowEvent page:

```
    <?php
    $dbhost = ''; //due to security problem, it will not show
    $dbuser = ''; //due to security problem, it will not show
    $dbpass = ''; //due to security problem, it will not show
    mysql_select_db('u507295856_ems');
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from event where Event_ID = '".$_REQUEST['eid']."'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        $output[]=$row;
        $JSON = json_encode($output);
        print ($JSON);
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Coding of the AndroidEvent page:

```
    <?php
    $dbhost = ''; //due to security problem, it will not show
    $dbuser = ''; //due to security problem, it will not show
    $dbpass = ''; //due to security problem, it will not show
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    mysql_select_db('u507295856_ems');
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from event order by Event_StartDate DESC");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        $output[]=$row;
        $JSON = json_encode($output);
        print ($JSON);
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

In Android App, it has one page is use ListView to display event name. This activity name is Activity_List. In this Activity_List class that can show event name in ListView. Coding of the Activity_List:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    setTitle("EMS");

    tvBack = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBack);
    tvEng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEng);
    tvCh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCh);
    lstActivity = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstActivity);

    tvBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_List.this, EMSActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    tvCh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_List.this, Activity_List.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    loadJSONFromWebAsync();
}

public void loadJSONFromWebAsync() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // http post
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://www.ems.cixx6.com/AndroidEvent.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                // convert response to string
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "change information losed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                Activity_List.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Activity_List.this.parseJSONAndRefreshListView();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "please check internet connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    t.run();
}

public void parseJSONAndRefreshListView() {
    // paring data
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int EventID = json_data.getInt("Event_ID");
            String event_Name = json_data.getString("Event_Name");
            myList.add(event_Name);
            myEventIDList.add("" + EventID);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
        lstActivity.setAdapter(adapter);

        lstActivity.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(Activity_List.this,
                        Activity_Detail.class);
                int selectedID = Integer.parseInt(myEventIDList.get(arg2));
                Log.i("test", Integer.toString(selectedID));
                i.putExtra("ID", selectedID);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "can not find information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When the user click one of the event, it will go to Activity_Detail class to watch event detail information. I want send selected event id to AndroidShowEvent php page. After, it connect to database to  select conform event ID record that display data in Activity_Detail class.
Activity_Detail page is use textView to display data.
Coding of the Activity_Detail :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    setTitle("EMS");

    tvBack = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBack);
    tvEng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEng);
    tvCh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCh);
    tvEventName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEventName);
    tvEventLocationID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEventLocation);
    tvEventDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEventDate);
    tvEventTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEventTime);
    tvEventPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEventPhone);
    tvSpeakerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSpeakerName);
    tvEventContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEventContent);
    imgEventBanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgEventBanner);
    BtnFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnFacebook);
    BtnTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnTwitter);

    tvEventLocationID.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Detail.this, PlaceMap.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    tvSpeakerName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Detail.this, Speaker.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    BtnFacebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    BtnTwitter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    tvBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Detail.this, EMSActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    tvCh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Detail.this,
                    Activity_Detail.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    EventID = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("ID", 0);

    String event = Integer.toString(EventID);
    Log.i("test", event);

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eid", event));
    Log.i("test",String.valueOf(params));
    loadJSONFromWebAsync(params);
}

public void loadJSONFromWebAsync(List<NameValuePair> pair) {
    final List<NameValuePair> _pair = pair;
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        //ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // http post
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://www.ems.cixx6.com/AndroidShowEvent.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(_pair));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                // convert response to string
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "change information losed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                Activity_Detail.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Activity_Detail.this.parseJSONAndRefreshListView();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "please check Internet connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    t.run();
}

public void parseJSONAndRefreshListView() {
    // paring data
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String Event_Name = json_data.getString("Event_Name");
            String Event_Location = json_data.getString("Event_Location");
            String Event_StartTime = json_data.getString("Event_StartTime");
            String Event_EndTime = json_data.getString("Event_EndTime");
            String Event_Phone = json_data.getString("Event_Phone");
            String Event_StartDate = json_data.getString("Event_StartDate");
            String Event_EndDate = json_data.getString("Event_EndDate");
            String Event_Description = json_data
                    .getString("Event_Description");
            String Event_Description2 = Event_Description.replace("<br>",
                    "\n");
            String Event_Image = json_data.getString("Event_Image");
            String Speaker_Name = json_data.getString("Speaker_Name");

            tvEventName.setText(Event_Name);
            tvEventDate.setText(Event_StartDate + " 至 " + Event_EndDate);
            tvEventTime.setText(Event_StartTime + " 至 " + Event_EndTime);
            tvEventPhone.setText(Event_Phone);
            tvEventContent.setText(Event_Description2);

            SpannableString contentUnderline = new SpannableString(
                    Event_Location);
            contentUnderline.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0,
                    contentUnderline.length(), 0);
            tvEventLocationID.setText(contentUnderline);

            SpannableString contentUnderline2 = new SpannableString(
                    Speaker_Name);
            contentUnderline2.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0,
                    contentUnderline2.length(), 0);
            tvSpeakerName.setText(contentUnderline2);

            Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("http://www.ems.cixx6.com/"
                    + Event_Image);
            imgEventBanner.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "can not find information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "please check Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Internet connection was losed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    return in;
}

private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

As a result. only displayed a Toast. message is "can not find information". other data has not displayed.

I purpose show suitable event data in Activity_Detail class.How do I should modify the code?

This question make me very trouble, please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

error message that by using e1.printStackTrace(); <-- Due to my reputation has not enough, so I can not post error message of image.

But my php coding has not error??

Because I suspect AndriodShowEvent php page can not get selected event id in android, therefore, it can not display detail information in Activity_Detail page.

Answer (score -1):

May be the problem with sending request or parsing the json.

Can you post the error message that you getting that by using  e1.printStackTrace();

Comment: This is not an answer. Use comments instead

Comment: Ok sorry. I am new to this stackoverflow and have not used this much. I did not see Add Comment to add comment your question.